# How to get local notification when user enters into specific region provided ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

I am working on such a project where apps do the following things:

1.Getting user current location.
   2. Get local notifications when user enters or nearby the particular locations i provided.

What i have done is:

I have downloaded the regions sample code(apple provided) to find out my current location using IOS corelocation framework.It works fine.here's the code below:

// Create a new region based on the center of the map view.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
CLRegion *newRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:2.0  identifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, regionsMapView.centerCoordinate.longitude]];
```

Now, my question is how to add specific regions with latitude& longitude to get notified?

Help is highly appreciated.Anybody knows any example or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the location-based services provided by the iOS Core Location framework.

here are some good tutorials. It may help you

- [Geofencing with Core Location](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/geofencing-with-core-location--mobile-15477)
- [Geofencing on iOS](http://www.creativebloq.com/ipad/get-started-geofencing-ios-9122867)
- [iOS Geofencing API Tutorial Using Core Location Framework](http://hayageek.com/ios-geofencing-api/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, current location and getting notification is works fine for me.but am confused at how to create particular location region with latitude and longitude. Please help me.

Comment: @user2704161 : In above tutorial, they have mentioned how to add specific region for monitoring

Comment: Thanks Rahul Patel, i hav downloaded the code and run that code. if i click on Add geofences, its showing region monitoring is not available for this class. How to get rid of that?

Comment: I think  regionMonitoringAvailable is deprecated in iOS 7.

Comment: Please check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/regionMonitoringEnabled

Answer (score 2):

The SetSDK should help make this super easy, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK. It allows you to setup notifications for user arrival and departure from locations. It currently learns those locations on the fly, but there is a coming release that includes arbitrary location subscription. Your app will receive a notification and you can execute whatever handler you want from there. It would look something like this,

```
SetSDK.instance.onArrival(to: .any) { newArrival in
    /* Compare the new location with the one of interest (50m) */
    if newArrival.location.distance(from: placeOfInterest) < 50 {
      /* do your things here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.Getting user current location.**

I have lengthy post and sample codes that I posted on my blog and Github on how to get location for iOS 7.

- [Background Location Update Programming for iOS 7](http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7)
- [Github Project: Background Location Update Programming for iOS 7](https://github.com/voyage11/Location)

**2. Get local notifications when user enters or nearby the particular locations i provided.**

You will have to use **startMonitoringForRegion** to monitor the region that you created.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D regionCentre = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
CLCircularRegion *region= [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:regionCentre radius:radius identifier:@"Name"];        
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

From the locationManager delegate, you will be notified when you enter the region.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message";        
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
{
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.timeZone = timezone;
notification.alertBody = message;
notification.alertAction = @"Show";
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
}
```