# location based alarm/notification ios

Tags: ios, notifications, location, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

I'm building an `iOS` app, however I want to get notification which may be a local and simple notification, such that on defined area of location, such that to provided the `latitude` and `longitude` to get the area around `200meter` and when the user entered in that location, it alerts the notification.

How can I schedule the `location` based local notification in `iOS`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get local notification when user enters into specific region provided ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535653/how-to-get-local-notification-when-user-enters-into-specific-region-provided-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what is available in the SetSDK, https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK. It will allow you to get notified whenever the user arrives to a new "location" (as learned on the fly by the sdk) and then just quickly evaluate to see if it is a location you care about. So it would look something like this,

```
SetSDK.instance.onArrival(to: .any) { newArrival in
    /* Compare the new location with the one of interest */
    if newArrival.location.distance(from: placeOfInterest) < 200 {
      /* do your things here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CLRegion` in combination with Background Location and your app will be woken up when the user enters that region. From there you can schedule a `UILocationNotification` for immediate display.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example code, I have a latitude and a longitude, and I want to get a localnotification on that region.